# Search using multiple dropdowns in laravel but get column not found error

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I want to search records using dropdowns like I select single dropdown then show its records or when when we select two or more dropdowns shows related record

I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'make LIKE "%"2"%"' in 'where clause'
> (SQL: select * from `products` where `make LIKE "%"2"%"` is null and `AND model LIKE "%"` .`$model`. `"%"` is null)

Here is my query for search:

```
$make = $request->make_dep; 
if($make != ''){$makekeyword = 'make LIKE "%"' . $make . '"%"';}

$model = $request->model;
if($model != ''){$modelkeyword = 'AND model LIKE "%" . $model . "%"';}

$products = DB::table('products')
            ->where($makekeyword)
            ->where($modelkeyword)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do  simplify it using 'like' operator:

```
 $products = DB::table('products');
        if($make != '')
            $products=$products->where('make','like','%'.$make.'%');
         if($model != '')
             $products=$products->where('model','like','%'.$model.'%');

$products = $products->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is   DB::table('products')->where($makekeyword) is adding `` to your where
> there fore it is considering this where:

```
 where `make LIKE "%"2"%"` 
is null and `AND model LIKE "%" `.` $model `.` "%"` is null)
as a column name
```